# Click using form name dont work using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my code for HTML:

This is a form that show after Click Here to Login

```
<div id="login">
    <button id="login">Click here to Login!</button>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  method="POST"  id="form2" name="form2">
        <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="Username" size="30" >
        <input name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"  size="30" >
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="sign up" name="signup">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my code for Jquery Ajax POST;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form[name='form2']").submit(function(e){
         var formEmail =  $('input[name=email]').val();
         var formPass = $('input[name=password').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/php/login.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                 alert("You are loggin!");
               // $("#show").html("Thank you for submit")

              //  $('#show').hide();
                $('#form1').hide();
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I have already tested with Postman and the server side works fine.

Comment: You haven't said what is the problem here.

Comment: What is the desired function and what is it not doing? Also, you've got a syntax error in your query selector: `$('input[name=password').val();` is missing the closing square bracket.

Comment: @mdziekon dont works the click button, dont get sucess or error statement of the ajax jquery.

Comment: @AdamMazzarella i already fixed that point, i have check in network and dont see any response.

Comment: Does `login.php` do `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`? That won't work with AJAX because `$(this).serialize()` doesn't include buttons.

Comment: Do you see the XHR *request* in the network tab? Is it returning an error code?

Comment: check the console errors

Comment: To be clear. You cicked the sign up button right?

Comment: @Omi i dont see any error in the console...

Comment: No,` if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))`

Comment: you have different names for input

Comment: @CaptainHere yes i clicked in signup but is for login...

Comment: That should be `if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass']))` (you have no input named "email" or "password")

Comment: @blex i have changed and dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's forget about the snippets you posted here and focus instead on the code you have on your website (since they are not exactly the same).

In your HTML code, you have this:

```
<div id="login">
    <button id="login">Click here to Login!</button>
    <!-- ... your form ... -->
</div>
```

Notice both the wrapping `div` and the `button` have the same ID. IDs are supposed to be unique, and that's causing a problem here.

Directly inside your page, you have this JS code:

```
$("#login").click(function(e){
    $("#form2").show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When you click on any element of the wrapping `div` (including the submit button), you are preventing the default behavior (ie: the form isn't submitted, nothing happens). But you only want to do this when the login button is clicked. To avoid this from happening on any other element, change the ID of the wrapping `div` to something else, and leave the JS code above as it is.

Then, since your form does not have a `name` attribute, your code won't work. Add one, or change your JS to use the ID instead (`#form2`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form2").submit(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/php/login.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("You are logged in!");
                $('#form2').hide();
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: let me understand, i have to put name in form and when i call form is usin     $("form[name='form2']").submit(function(e){
? Can you clarify YOUR answer

Comment: @JcoderMan To clarify: **Step 1.** Change the ID of `<div id="login">` to something else (for example `login-wrapper`). **Step 2.** Add `name="form2"` to your HTML form, and it should send the form correctly when using `$("form[name='form2']").submit(...)`